# i keep getting location null when using current location

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, location, geofire

I am trying to use Geoquery to find the other closest users in my radius. In my app I have a button that when pressed calls a function named findClosestCars which uses geoQuery to the closest users in my radius. In order to use Geoquery I need to grab my latitide and longitude. To do this I am storing the latitude and longitude in double type variables named latitude and longitude. The latitude and longitude is getting grabbed by a location object named currentlocation like this latitude=currentLocation.getLatitude(),longitude=currentLocation.getLongitude(). Instead of using fusedlocation I am trying to get the current location to populate the object currentLocation. Below is my code for findClosestCars

```
    private void findClosestCars() {


        latitude=currentLocation.getLatitude();
       longitude=currentLocation.getLongitude();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Lenders");
        GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(databaseReference);
        GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), radius);
        geoQuery.removeAllListeners();

        geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {

                if (!driverFound) {
                    driverFound = true;
                    driverFoundID = key;

                    closestLender = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("Lenders").child(driverFoundID);
;



                 showPictureAndPrice();
                }

                radius++;


            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyExited(String key) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryReady() {

                if (!driverFound) {
                    radius++;
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Below is the code to grab the current location and put it in the variable currentLocation

```
 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {



        currentLocation=location;

    }
    protected synchronized void builGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
    }
```

Comment: How is this question related to Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

You're checking permissions, but not requesting them if you don't already have them.  You need to do that.